# How to make dropdown "Searchable" using Angular JS & HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

HTML:

```
enter code here

<select  ng-model="selection.count"  ng-options="name.Country for name in      dataset | unique:'Country' | orderBy: 'Country'"   ng-change="onDropClick()" ng-click="barChart()" overflow-y:scroll >
</select>
```

I want the dropdown to have a search bar and then display the selected option

Answer (score 0):

you can use google search box instead. https://cse.google.com/cse/all